# Python requests Google search result encounters cookie page

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm using Python requests module to get a Google search results page, when I run it in my own PC it gets the result fine, but when I run it in an AWS Windows VM instance it gets the Google cookie landing page instead, how do I bypass that and get the results page straight?

```
import requests


result = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=usd+in+myr").text
print(result)
```

Weird thing is in my own PC when I open the page inside Chrome browser incognito mode I expect to see the cookie page but I don't, meanwhile in the AWS Windows VM it does show the cookie landing page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set `cookies` parameter in `requests.get` with `CONSENT=` key:

```py
import requests


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/113.0'}
cookies = {'CONSENT':"YES+cb.20220419-08-p0.cs+FX+111"}

result = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=usd+in+myr", headers=headers, cookies=cookies).text
print(result)
```

Comment: thanks that worked, though i wonder why did it not encounter the cookies landing page when i opened the page in browser incognito mode in my PC